# How to calculate exact stroke-dasharray values for seamless animation

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations, stroke-dasharray

I am trying to `animate` the `stroke-dashoffset` property of a svg element as following

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

//const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

var ln = document.querySelector('.ln');
var path = ln.getTotalLength();

ln.style.setProperty("--off", path + 'px');
svg.appendChild(ln);
```

```css
.ln {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--off);
    stroke-dasharray: 13;
    animation: effect 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes effect {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <svg id="layer" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  
  <rect class="boundary" x="100" y="100" height="100" width="130" fill="none" stroke="blue"></rect>
  <line class="ln" x1="100" y1="150" x2="230" y2="150"  stroke = "grey" stroke-width="2" />
  <script href="index.js"></script>
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```

An important part of this animation is the `stroke-dasharray` value.

I have realized that based on the value of that field, the animation can feel either seamless or not seamless.

For example, with values like `5 and 13` the animation feels seamless. For any other value, the animation is jumpy.

Also, I have realized that 5 and 13 respectively produce

[image: S1] [image: S2]

where the dashes start from exactly the left and does not have any residual as opposed to what
`stroke-dasharray =6, 10` does

[image: S3]
[image: S4]

How can I calculate the **`exact and safest`** `stroke-dasharray` values for varying `path` length which will make the lines starts from exactly the left with no residual that will produce the seamless feel rather than finding it through endless trial and error?

Comment: Try setting a `pathLength" and adjusting your offset and array accordingly - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eYyOLMv - No need to calculate it at all.

Comment: In my case, I will be applying the effect on numerous svg elements of varying `path length`, it becomes impossible for me to do this on trial and error basis.  For example, in your example if you change `stroke-dashoffset: 30; stroke-dasharray: 10;` things go sideways. I want to know how to calculate so that the problem can be resolved with js once and for all.

Comment: The point is that you won't have varying `pathLength` since you can set this manually so your offset/array can always be the same

Comment: use ``pathLength``; see: https://css-tricks.com/a-trick-that-makes-drawing-svg-lines-way-easier/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out.

Let's suppose the **`path length=120px`** and the **`stroke-dasharray=10px`**.

The `stroke-dasharray=10` creates a **`10px wide dash + 10px wide gap`** like this

[image: S1]

If the `total path length divided by each (dash+gap)` (20px in this case) `returns 0`; that means all the elements (120 px/each stoke-dasharray of 10px *2[dash+gap]) = 6 sets (6 dash + 6 gaps) can perfectly fit in. If the division returns remainder then that `dash array` value will not result in a perfect fit of the elements.

With this knowledge, the logic can be passed on to js to pull the strings

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var x = 100;
var y = 100;
var height = 100;
var width = 120;
var midHeight = height / 2;


let boundary = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
boundary.setAttribute("x", x);
boundary.setAttribute("y", y);
boundary.setAttribute("height", height);
boundary.setAttribute("width", width);
boundary.setAttribute("fill", "none");
boundary.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
svg.appendChild(boundary);

let line = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'line');
line.setAttribute("class", "ln")
line.setAttribute("x1", x);
line.setAttribute("x2", x + width);
line.setAttribute("y1", x + midHeight);
line.setAttribute("y2", x + midHeight);
line.setAttribute("stroke", "grey");
line.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
svg.appendChild(line);



var ln = document.querySelector('.ln');
var path = ln.getTotalLength();

var halfPath = path / 2;

var possibleNumbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < halfPath; i++) {
    (halfPath % i) == 0 && (i != 1) ? possibleNumbers.push(i) : 0
};

ln.style.setProperty("--off", path + 'px');
ln.style.setProperty("--arr", possibleNumbers[5] + 'px');
svg.appendChild(ln);
```

```css
.ln {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--off);
    stroke-dasharray: var(--arr);
    animation: effect 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes effect {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <svg id="layer" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  
   <script href="index.js"></script>
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```